# Custom angular version in jsfiddle

Tags: angularjs, jsfiddle

How can I load a custom angular version into jsfiddle?

I want to use version 1.1.5 and not 1.1.1.

I would appreciate a working jsfiddle example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the left side bar, in "External Resources", add a link to the AngularJS library. For example from the Google CDN:

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js

Comment: Here's an example if you need it still: fiddle.net/QFNLW/

Answer (score 3):

Go into the External Resources Tab in the left sidebar:
[image: left side bar]

Then add the url for a CDN that hosts Angular 1.1.5 `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js`:
[image: add url]

Click the "+" button and you are all set:
[image]

**UPDATE**

Also, don't forget to set the framework to "No-Library (pure JS)" unless you want to use another framework such as jquery.  Just don't set it to another version on angular

**UPDATE**

Here's a JSFiddle with Angular 1.1.5 working
http://jsfiddle.net/QFNLW/

Comment: Although your pics are nice, you could've cropped them :P +1 anyway